# symfony route gives no response

Tags: php, symfony, routes, entity

as said, my problem is I get an empty response (looked in firebug) when calling a route on a post method. placing a "die('something')" shows me the action isn't called... I have no idea where the request is handled.... 
An important thing could be **I renamed an entity** and all that was related (controllers, forms ...) it works fine except when trying to call Contact -> createAction via my route :

```
contact_create:
    path:     /create
    defaults: { _controller: "MainMainBundle:Contact:create" }
    requirements: { _method: post|put }
```

I receive empty response.. even if i call it via get method, no error, empty response...

action in controller :

public function createAction(Request $request) { ...

I really dont know if there's something obvious in front of me, and I dont see it, or could it be a kind of routing cache, messing up with the renaming of the routes, controllers, entity...

If anyone has an idea, i'd be very thankul !

regards

EDIT:
contact.yml :

```
contact:
    path:     /{companyId}
    defaults: { _controller: "MainMainBundle:Contact:index" }

contact_show:
    path:     /{id}/show
    defaults: { _controller: "MainMainBundle:Contact:show" }

contact_new:
    path:     /new/{companyId}
    defaults: { _controller: "MainMainBundle:Contact:new" }

contact_create:
    path:     /create
    defaults: { _controller: "MainMainBundle:Contact:create" }
    requirements: { _method: post|put }

contact_edit:
    path:     /{id}/edit
    defaults: { _controller: "MainMainBundle:Contact:edit" }

contact_update:
    path:     /{id}/update
    defaults: { _controller: "MainMainBundle:Contact:update" }
    requirements: { _method: post|put }

contact_delete:
    path:     /{id}/delete
    defaults: { _controller: "MainMainBundle:Contact:delete" }
    requirements: { _method: post}

contact_revive:
    path:     /{id}/revive
    defaults: { _controller: "MainMainBundle:Contact:revive" }
    requirements: { _method: post}
```

---

```
$ php app/console router:debug | grep contact

deal_ajax_load_new_form           ANY             ANY    ANY  /deal/dealajaxloadnewform/{contactId}
contact                           ANY             ANY    ANY  /contact/{companyId}
contact_show                      ANY             ANY    ANY  /contact/{id}/show
contact_new                       ANY             ANY    ANY  /contact/new/{companyId}
contact_create                    POST|PUT        ANY    ANY  /contact/create
contact_edit                      ANY             ANY    ANY  /contact/{id}/edit
contact_update                    POST|PUT        ANY    ANY  /contact/{id}/update
contact_delete                    POST            ANY    ANY  /contact/{id}/delete
contact_revive                    POST            ANY    ANY  /contact/{id}/revive
```

Comment: what method are you using to request the route? POST or GET?

Comment: I am using a POST method, i tried to GET it, in order to see an error, but no error...

Comment: show us your whole routing, you may have conflicting routes ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try placing 'contact_create' route on top of contact.yml, I suppose that first route on that file 'contact' is matching with "/create" path (companyId = create) and executing "MainMainBundle:Contact:index" controller instead of "MainMainBundle:Contact:create" one.

Comment: Thanks a lot ! I had forgotten that the router would select the first route that fits to the pattern ! I'll have to discriminate the patterns a little more.. thanks again !

Answer (score 0):

Are you using jsrouting-bundle (friendsofsymfony) ? If so, try running the following command

```
app/console fos:js-routing:dump
```

Comment: No, I'm using the base routing

Answer (score 0):

Check if you use correct port. In my case port was 8080 but I was using 8000